# With letters represented as 2 digit numbers, converting a large number into a word

Tags: c++

I have the following problem:

The letters a to z are represented by the numbers 10 - 35 e.g. a = 10, b = 11 ... z = 35

Given an integer how would you go about converting it into a word/sentence if each 2 digits of the number represent a letter? (the integer is the output of a decrypt process and so will always be applicable for conversion).

e.g 31232612 ---> "word"

I think that the best way to do this would be to split the integer into 2-digit chunks using % and determining the size of the number using log to the base 10? I'm unsure of exactly how this would work and I'm really interested in how other people would solve this problem.

I'm not sure whether to upload any code I have already or whether to leave it blank so in case anybody wants to give it a go from a clean slate, so just let me know.

Thanks for any feedback! (my first impression is that everything which is trivial is assumed to be homework so I thought that I would say that this isn't, I'm just doing it because I'm trying to improve and I find this kind of thing fun and thought I would share).

Comment: I think you should go ahead with your approach. You can use % operator to find 2 digit numbers and then use ascii to convert it into char by simply adding a constant. You could keep pushing it into a stack and them pop them to get the word.

Comment: I can convert a 2 digit number to a letter, I'm just having problems with the 'splitting' into 2 letter chunks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by splitting ? Do you mean splitting the big integer into smaller two digit parts ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

```
int main()
{
   int numb=31231712;
   std::stack<char> mystack;
   int mod;
   while ((mod=numb%100)!=numb){
       char c=mod+88;
       mystack.push(c);
       numb=numb/100;
   }
   char c=mod+88;
   mystack.push(c);
   while (!mystack.empty())
   {
      cout << mystack.top();
      mystack.pop();
   }
   cout << '\n';
}
```

It will print the word in reverse, I do not know if 88 is the right choice but that is an adjustable parameter use the ascii table. To take care of the reverse, just push all the chars in a stack. Afterwards, pop the stack till empty to get the word right.

Comment: Btw 31231712 -/-> "word",
it is 31232612

Comment: I think it's 87, and I'll fix the error with "word". I'll give this a go and let you know, thanks a lot!

Comment: You were correct with 88, how would I go about reversing it so that it appears in the correct order?

Comment: As I said in my answer, use a std::stack in c++. Instead of cout, keep pushing char into the stack, when the last character is added to the stack, make a loop to empty the stack by poping chars from the stack until it is empty.

Comment: I'll google what you said and see if I can do it! Thanks so much <3

Comment: My code works, but I don't why he doesn't accept it! I lost my reputations! Hey buddy, let us up vote each other's answers ;)
First, I vote for you.

Comment: I get an error message saying that "`stack` is not a member of `std`" and thanks again.

Comment: You have to include the <stack> stl container. Please mark this answer as accepted if your problem is solved.

Comment: @Wajahat I up voted you, don't you wanna vote for me? I lost my reputations while my code is working fine!

Comment: You might have lost your rep due to other reasons, why are you crying

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code, I think it can help you :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main () {

   string word = "";
   string integer;
   cin >> integer;

   for (int i = integer.size() - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2) {

           int temp = integer[i] - '0';
       if (i)
        temp += 10 * (integer[i - 1] - '0');

       word += (char)('a' + (temp - 10) + 1);
   }

   reverse(word.begin(), word.end());
   cout << word << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't vote it up because I don't have 15 reputation and get a message saying "you must have 15 reputation to vote this up", also when I run this it doesn't work for me, I'm not sure why, I just get a blank output.